# JMeter 3.2 version - SOAP Request

Tags: soap, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

How I can make test SOAP Request in JMeter version 3.2? In old version I had Soap/XML-RPC Data sampler while in version 3.2 I don't see this option. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, in case you need to set some headers like [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) or [SOAPAction](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html) you can use [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

You can see [Building a WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) article for more information if required.