# How to remove an obsolete element in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, obsolete

I use Jmeter 3.2 version. I updated the old request and now I need to remove the obsolete element. Right click on the element doesn't give any context menu.
Open the file with 2.11 jmeter is not an option for me as it require java7. I don't have it and to install anything on my work machine I need approvement from our admin. It will take ages.
So is there a way to remove the obsolete element in jmeter 3.2?
Thanks.

Comment: what's the obsolete element?

Comment: @user7294900 SOAP/XML-RPC Request which is not longer supported.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233715/jmeter-3-2-version-soap-request

Comment: @user7294900 thanks, but as I mentioned in description I already updated the request. Now I need to remove the old one. that's the problem.

Comment: you can open jmeter 2.11 with java 8 (just did) and remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open jmx file in JMeter 2.11 also with Java 8.

If you somehow can't open for some reason you can edit file and remove the following tags (hashTree with SoapSampler inside):

```
  <hashTree>
    <SoapSampler guiclass="SoapSamplerGui" testclass="SoapSampler" testname="SOAP/XML-RPC Request" enabled="true">
      <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="SoapSampler.URL_DATA"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSamper.xml_data"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="SoapSampler.xml_data_file"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="SoapSampler.SOAP_ACTION"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="SoapSampler.SEND_SOAP_ACTION">true</stringProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
    </SoapSampler>
    <hashTree/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found even easier way:

- select the obsolete element (left click)
- click 'Cut' button.